# Java: (false?) positive S2637 in SonarQube 6.7.1 LTS

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 6.7.1 LTS on a Java project and I analyze it using Maven sonar plugin.

I have the following code example, which finds an S2637 issue in method `testGregorianCalendar2`:

```
public static final @Nonnull Calendar testGregorianCalendar1() {
    return GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
}

public static final @Nonnull Calendar testGregorianCalendar2() {
    return setTimeZone2(GregorianCalendar.getInstance());
}

public static final Calendar setTimeZone2(final Calendar inputCalendar) {
    if (null == inputCalendar) {
        return null;
    }
    return inputCalendar;
}

public static final @Nonnull Calendar testGregorianCalendar3() {
    return setTimeZone3(GregorianCalendar.getInstance());
}

public static final Calendar setTimeZone3(final Calendar inputCalendar) {
    return inputCalendar;
}
```

> In the methods `testGregorianCalendar1` and `testGregorianCalendar3`, that issue is not found by Sonar.
>   I think in `testGregorianCalendar2`, it should also not be found, or it should be found in all 3 methods `testGregorianCalendar*`, because:

Sonar should decide for itself, if `GregorianCalendar.getInstance()` can return null or not.
If yes, all 3 methods can return null and Sonar should find the issue in all of these methods.

If no, then the method `setTimeZone2` is called with a non-null value, and it will then return a non-null value, so `testGregorianCalendar2` will return a non-null value.

What is going wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure, but here's what I would guess is happening: `setTimeZone2` has a conditional `return null`, therefore returning the return value from `setTimeZone2` from a `@Nonnull` method is not allowed without a check for that null value.

That is, the analyzer sees:

```
public static final Calendar setTimeZone2(final Calendar inputCalendar) {
    if (/* something */) {
        return null;
    }
    return /* null if inputCalendar is null */;
}
```

And it determines: the return value of `setTimeZone2` is (potentially) `@Nullable`.

Then it sees:

```
public static final @Nonnull Calendar testGregorianCalendar2() {
    return setTimeZone2(/* something */);
}
```

And it sees a potentially `@Nullable` value being returned from a method marked `@Nonnull`, which produces a warning.

You and I can reason that `setTimeZone2` will never return null unless `inputCalendar` is null, and that `inputCalendar` can never be null because `GregorianCalendar.getInstance()` will never return null, but the analyzer probably isn't evaluating under *what* condition `setTimeZone2` can return null, just that it can under *some* condition.

Comment: Spot on. It's a static code analysis tool. To establish possible or impossible values (including `null`), SonarCube would have to compile, build it and run it, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @diginoise: A sufficiently advanced static analysis tool *could* prove that this code is safe -- it's not really much harder than definite assignment analysis or escape analysis, which the compiler and JIT already do. (For example, I bet if this were a performance hotspot, the JIT would inline the `setTimeZone2` method and then the peephole optimizer would elide the null check entirely.) But Sonar probably just didn't implement this kind of analysis because it's a lot of work and the cases where it makes a meaningful difference (like this one) are much rarer than where it wouldn't help.

Comment: @DanielPryden your explanation is almost correct, but you are doing some wrong assumptions on how the symbolic execution engine of the SonarJava analyzer is working. In this context, you explanation of how we interpret method `setTimeZone2` is wrong. The rest is not too far from real behavior. SonarJava is opensource, so you can still have a look at the engine there: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/tree/master/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/se